# Ajax not displaying error message itself, box only

Tags: ajax, laravel

For some reason AJAX is not passing the error message. Whatever I try to submit in my form, I get red line (error message style) but without error message init, which makes hard for me to debug. Any ideas what is causing error message not to be displayed?

My AJAX function, pointing to store method in TicketCategory controller:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-add").click(function() { 
        $.ajaxSetup({ 
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ticket-category/store',
            data: {
                name: $("#frmAddTicketCategory input[name=name]").val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json', 
                $('#frmAddTicketCategory').trigger("reset");
                $("#frmAddTicketCategory .close").click();
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $('#add-ticket-category-errors').html('');
                $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                    $('#add-ticket-category-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                });
                $("#add-error-bag").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

My view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addTicketCategoryModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="frmAddTicketCategory">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        Add New Task
                    </h4>
                    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                        ×
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="add-error-bag">
                        <ul id="add-ticket-category-errors">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            Name
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" value="Cancel">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn-add" type="button" value="add">
                            Add New Task
                        </button>
                    </input>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('ticket_category/ticket_cat',[
        'tickets' => TicketCategory::all()
    ]);
}

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), array(
            'name' => 'required'
        ));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error'    => true,
                'messages' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 422);
        }

        $ticket_category = TicketCategory::create([$request->name]);

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'ticket_category'  => $ticket_category,
        ], 200);
    }
```

[see the error issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ9yV.png)

Comment: There is no issue no code, check sample -https://jsfiddle.net/517xc9av/  you need to check what is value of errors. Try to console that and then code accordingly

Comment: It is because `$validator->errors()` will return errors in array format, you need to pass it as a `json encoded` format

Answer (score 0):

I think `value` is an array of errors for a field that is why you are not able to display the errors. Try this

```
$('#add-ticket-category-errors').append('<li>' + value[0] + '</li>')
```

Comment: That didn't work - I don't think it's related to value since it is being passed as key-value $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(value)`  and you `console.log(errors.messages[key])`

Comment: console.log(value); returns error message 500 : (Internal Server Error), so I assume that is the reason why the error is not displayed